# What happens with race-rep when you racechange?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

A thing I am wondering about, but dont want to test out as it will at least cost me 40 bucks is, what happens to the rep you get from picking a race, when you change it afterwards.

I'm currently thinking about the nightborne. When you start as one you immediatly have the nightborne rep as exalted. What heppens if you play with it for a while and sometime choose to change to some other race?

Will it stay at exalted? Will it go to neutral, or revert to what you earned manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a [topic over at the battle.net forums](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/wow/topic/2416193211), blizzard indicates that they will **swap** your racial reputation with that of the new race. The official KB article about this has been moved though so the link is broken now, but it should still function in the same way, as it seems to be a very sensible solution from the developer's standpoint. So, for example;

A dwarf has an 'Exalted' reputation with Ironforge, and a 'Friendly' with Stormwind. After changing their race to a Human, they will now be 'Exalted' with Stormwind, and 'Friendly' with Ironforge.

Whether the developers thought to close the loophole with the Nightborne specifically I can't expound on currently, there may be an exception in place.